# number of samples for a function plot not working with pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots

I need to plot representations of the delta function on the same axis.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ 
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel={$\delta_{\varepsilon}(x-x_0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi\varepsilon}}\exp\left[\frac{-(x-x_0)^2}{4\varepsilon}\right]$}, ticks= none, axis x line=bottom,axis y line=left,mark=none, ultra thick
  ] 
   % \addplot[mark=none, ultra thick, red,samples=150] {sin(deg(x))/(pi*x)}; 
    \addplot[mark=none,  thick, blue,samples=500] {exp(-(x*x)/(4*1*0.8))/sqrt(4*pi*0.8)};
     \addplot[mark=none,  thick, red,samples=1000] {exp(-((x)*(x))/(4*1*0.2))/sqrt(4*pi*0.2)};
     \addplot[mark=none,  thick, green,samples=900] {exp(-((x)*(x))/(4*1*0.04))/sqrt(4*pi*0.04)};
     \draw (100pt,130pt) node [right, green] {$\varepsilon = 0.04$};
     \draw (110pt,60pt) node [right, red] {$\varepsilon = 0.2$};
     \draw (140pt,20pt) node [right, blue] {$\varepsilon = 0.8$};
     \draw (100pt,-0pt) node [thick, below] {$x_0$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But no matter how many sample points I choose, the plots are still not smooth.

[image]

How can I get smooth plots?

**EDIT**
File list is

```
*File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
inputenc.sty    2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
pgfplots.sty    2009/02/14 Version 1.2.2
    tikz.sty    2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)
     pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
  pgfrcs.sty    2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2009/08/28 v1.8 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2010/03/12 v0.04p Graphics/color for pdfTeX
  pgfsys.sty    2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
supp-pdf.mkii
  deltaF.tex
integral.tex
exponential.tex
 ***********
```

Comment: Could you add `\listfiles` to your input and copy the resulting `File list` from your `.log` into the question? The example looks fine to me so I suspect a version issue.

Comment: @JosephWright, added the File list.

Comment: your pgfplots version is too old. Current version is 1.12.1 and you have 1.2.2. Update the TikZ version to v3.0.0 too while you are at it. In fact update your TeX distribution if you can anyways :)

Comment: @percusse, Thanks for the suggestion, I have updated the Tex distribution and examples seems to be working.

Comment: Ah great. Do you mind if we close this question then as there is not much left to answer?

Comment: @percusse Yes, surely..!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is caused by an outdated package version.